# Trying to start a sound file with a shake gesture without UIButton

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

Tried inserting my code but this site rejected it.  The code was legit for using a UIButton but I can't figure out how to exclude the UIButton from the code and still get it to work right.  Any suggestions?

By the way I am using AVFoundation

I try copying the code straight over from xcode and it tells me it is not indented by four spaces so really really irritating because I have code.

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion WithEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{
    NSLog(@"Device started shaking!");
    clicked = 1;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/FightSong.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

The clicked refers to the integer of a UIButton that the motion is setting off to start the audio file but I want to get rid of the UIButton and still have the shake gesture initiate the audio file.

Comment: can you edit this post more clearly ?